# Why visual studio compiler embeds variable names as strings in the compiled EXE?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am compiling some program i wrote, and when i run `strings.exe` (from sysinternals, a tool which displays the strings in a binary file) i see variable names from my code.

I am using visual studio C++ compiler, i already tried to disable debug info generation and playing with the project properties but nothing helped so far.

Has anyone encountered this problem before?
Thanks.

EDIT:

as requested, the compilations command lines.

compiler:

```
/permissive- /Yu"pch.h" /GS- /analyze- /W3 /Zc:wchar_t /Zi /Gm- /Od /sdl /Fd"Debug\vc141.pdb" /fp:precise /D "WIN32" /D "_DEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /errorReport:prompt /GF- /WX- /Zc:forScope /RTCs /GR- /Gd /Oy- /MTd /FC /Fa"Debug\" /nologo /Fo"Debug\" /Fp"Debug\a.pch" /diagnostics:classic
```

linker:

```
/OUT:"C:\a.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT:NO /FUNCTIONPADMIN /PDB:"C:\a.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /FIXED:NO /DEBUG /MACHINE:X86 /INCREMENTAL:NO /PGD:"C:\a.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"Debug\a.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /TLBID:1
```

Comment: Is this CLR ( .Net framework ) or a debug build?

Comment: This is very weird for native code. Variable names in particular make no sense whatsoever to be in the actual executable (at most it should be in the pdb). Only exported/imported methods would make sense. I can't reproduce it with VS2017 either  - can you show sample code and which VS version you're using?

Comment: Surely you saw type names, not variable names.  RTTI at work, turn on by default.

Comment: I clearly saw variable **names**, not types..
This is a debug build but everything is set to minimize debug output, also - **CLR** Support is set to NO.
i am using visual studio 2017 community.

Comment: Best post a small sample project and include the command lines for the compilation/linking (you can get that from the option page). That way we should be able to see if we can reproduce this or what the problem might be.

Comment: I would expect this to go away in a Release build.

Comment: as requested, i added the command lines.

Comment: Nope, can't reproduce this at all. Probably will need a whole csproj, but I'm tending towards misinterpreting the output of strings or something.